# Jquery target a div in after() event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-after

i have a very small problem . i have an input field that has a button to create an instance of it when clicked . Everything works fine when the click event is initiated but the problem comes when i target the element that was generated with `after()` , i can't seem to do that . please see the code below

HTML

```
<div class="after-add-more form-group">
    <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Something here">
</div>

    <!-- Copy Fields -->
<div class="copy hide">
    <div class="form-group more-duty">
        <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control try" placeholder="Enter More stuffs here">
        <button class="remove" type="button">Remove Stuff</button>
    </div>
</div>

<button class="add-more" type="button">Add Stuff</button>
```

Javascript

```
$(".add-more").click(function(){ 
     var html = $(".copy").html();
     $(".after-add-more").after(html);
});

$("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
     $(this).parents(".more-duty").remove();
});

$('.try').click(function() {
     alert("Ouch");
});
```

When i click the generated input so as i can echo ouch , the event is not called.please see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bobin56/xqa8d8pc/) .  Any help will be appreciated . Thanks .

Comment: So the issue is that you want the new input and button to be placed last in the listing, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need event delegation, Same as you did it for `.remove` class click like,

```
$("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
  $(this).parents(".more-duty").remove();
}).on('click', '.try', function() {
  alert("Ouch");
});
```

```js
$(".add-more").click(function() {
  var html = $(".copy").html();
  $(".after-add-more").after(html);
});

$("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
  $(this).parents(".more-duty").remove();
}).on('click', '.try', function() {
  alert("Ouch");
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="after-add-more form-group">
  <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Something here">
</div>

<!-- Copy Fields -->
<div class="copy hide">
  <div class="form-group more-duty">
    <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control try" placeholder="Enter More stuffs here">
    <button class="remove" type="button">Remove Stuff</button>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="add-more" type="button">Add Stuff</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".add-more").click(function() {
  var html = $(".copy").html();
  $(".after-add-more").after(html);
});

$("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
  $(this).parents(".more-duty").remove();
});
$(document).on("click",'.try',function() {//use .on()
  alert("Ouch");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="after-add-more form-group">
  <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Something here">
</div>

<!-- Copy Fields -->
<div class="copy hide">
  <div class="form-group more-duty">
    <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control try" placeholder="Enter More stuffs here">
    <button class="remove" type="button">Remove Stuff</button>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="add-more" type="button">Add Stuff</button> Javascript
```

It is dynamically added so use `.on()`

Answer (score 0):

$ ( "body" ).on( " click ", " .try " , function( ) {

```
     alert( " Ouch " );
```

} );

/**this will work. In your case it was not working because the click event was not bind with the Element because it was generated afterwords*/